# Траектория полёта пули, raycast. Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

В моей игре (C#) можно стрелять по врагам. Управлять траекторией можно джойстиком или мышью (по выбору игрока). Также в игре есть препятствия с тегом "Ground" и враги с тегом "Enemy". Мне бы хотелось добавить линию, исходящую из оружия по направлению траектории, которая, когда игрок наводит оружие на врага (имеется ввиду, что если выстрелить из ружья, то пуля по траекторию попадёт во врага), линия становится зелёной. Если же траектория стрельбы оружия не наведена на врага, то линия загорается красным цветом. Хочу подметить: нужно,чтобы линия не проходила сковзь препятствия и врагов,а упиралась в них. Вопрос: как это реализовать? Я очень плохо объясняю, так что если есть вопросы или вы хотите узнать подробности, то я обязательно отвечу. Скрипты могу скинуть, если вы попростите. Ниже показаны скриншоты, как выглядит игра сейчас, и как бы мне хотелось реализовать линию. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Как хотелось бы реализовать:
[image: How i want] [image: How i want]Как сейчас: [image: Now]

Answer (score 0):

Обычная математика
Координаты пули:

```
x=x0 + cos(angle)*v
y=y0 + sin(angle)*v
```

Где x0 и y0 место,откуда начала двигаться пуля(т.е. положение игрока)

angle это угол ,под которым летит.Хочу заметить ,что угол должен быть в радианах а не в градусах.Как перевести градусы в радианы? Легко,взять градусы и разделить на 180 а затем умножить на пи

v - скорость пули

`angle = degress/180*3.14`

где degress это угол под которым будет стрельба от 0 до 360

Comment: спасибо! Попробую сделать. А как только менять цвета при соприкосновении с обьктами (tag == "Enemy")?

Comment: это уже в зависимости от кода,я же не знаю ,что там у вас :)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо. только важно: линия должна не рисоваться во время выстрела пули, а ДО, как-бы предугадывая траекторию пули.

Comment: В таком случаи используйте v не как скорость ,а как длину линии

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: добрый день! в виду малого опыта и недостатка знаний в программировании, я не понял самое главное - как именно отрисовать линию? да, координаты мы посчитали, но как изобразить саму линию?